# Why murder the useful familiar in 30 Days of Night?

Tags: vampire, 30-days-of-night

Seems like the familiar who does the advance work for the vampires is pretty much the "Renfield" of this movie. The common idea is a crazy guy who is intensely loyal expecting often but not always to be made into a vampire -- sometimes there is apparently a familiar who serves without expectation of eventual conversion.

The familiar in 30 Days of Night is implied to me a probably mentally ill and homeless person who is just thrilled with the prospect of improving his situation by transformation.

He performed his fairly complex duties in Barrow competently -- why was he killed? Would he not be useful further?

It seems like in some stories, the craziness of the familiar might be the reason: he won't shut up about his "master" or whatever; but in Barrow he can't jeopardize anything so this is different than the actual Renfield who might lead people to Dracula's caskets perhaps.

I would argue that a competent familiar, even if not considered "vampire material" is not easy to find. They are a combination of being desperate and yet intelligent enough to accomplish complex and dangerous tasks. So finding them might be pretty hard.

One possible idea is his being murdered quickly is the "reward" a familiar who has done what is asked of him and yet is not on the list of those intended for conversion: no more stringing along and probably shortening a pretty unpleasant position -- probably when among vampires, the familiar being at the bottom of the totem pole, is bullied like crazy and perhaps fed from which I would guess is a very unpleasant experience if not done to convert all at once -- it is portrayed as literally "draining" (and perhaps all at once is no fun either but it has the conversion as the bonus).

Perhaps the 30 days ahead of the vampires is a big "outing" or carnival (literally again) for them and they would either not want a human whom they could not kill around or they would not control themselves so the Danny Huston character is again being merciful?

Comment: @Davidw: Simple question: Why murder a useful familiar? I can't believe that does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I am an expert on vampires... (can anyone be an expert on such a subject?)  But I have been exposed to a great deal of lore...
I had the same thoughts when I watched the movie.  The vampires don't seem to place much stock in loyalty, do they?
I believe that one of your core assumptions is incorrect:  "I would argue that a competent familiar...is not easy to find."  I would postulate that they might be fairly easy to come by.  After all, we live in an age where some people get married to serial killers.
I see a few ways that vampires might recruit familiars.  Hypnotic seduction.  In many vampire tales, the vampire is gifted with the power of suggestion.  Desire for immortality.  You mention this one.  Shear terror.  The shock of learning that vampires exist by dint of the fact that one is standing right in front of you and just killed your buddy, coupled with the knowledge that it can find you any time it wants... That might be enough to get me begging to switch sides.  Stockholm syndrome, vampire style...  Heck, maybe flies really are tasty.
In this case, a familiar would be a disposable commodity, not even worth feeding off of, like milk left out in the sun.  Milk that had an annoying whine...

Comment: well, it is possible that vampires have no trouble finding recruits for familiars but given that they put themselves in vulnerable positions that the familiar can take advantage of, it still seems to me that once u find a loyal and competent familiar, you would try to keep it. in 30 Days, the virus itself made humans loyal (i think -- one could rebel also) but the familiar is not exposed yet.